# Azure push notification API to get total outgoing notifications and number of registered devices

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub, azure-sdk-.net

How can I retrieve number of total outgoing notifications and number of  registered devices ? Does MS Azure provide any API to do that ? I want to retrieve result in JSON or XML.
thank you for your replay.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xpT5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I retrieve number of total outgoing notifications and number of registered devices ? Does MS Azure provide any API to do that ?

We could use the [Azure monitor REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list) to do that.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/{resourceUri}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?timespan={timespan}&interval={interval}&metric={metric}&aggregation={aggregation}&$top={$top}&$orderby={$orderby}&$filter={$filter}&resultType={resultType}&api-version=2017-05-01-preview
```

We could get the supported metrics by Azure monitor from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics).The resourceUri in your case is

```
var resourceUri = $"subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.NotificationHubs/Namespaces/{notificationamespace}/NotificationHubs/{notificationHubName}";
```

If you want to get the registered devices ,from the [Supported metrics with Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics), we could know that. **metric = registration.all**

If you want to get total outgoing notifcations **metric = notificationhub.pushes**

---

We also could do that with Azure SDK [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent/1.3.0-beta). The following is the demo code. How to  get the tenatId, secretKey or application please refer to [Create an Azure Active Directory application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application)

```
var azureTenantId = "tenantId";
var azureSecretKey = "secret key";
var azureAppId = "Application Id";
var subscriptionId = "subscription Id";
var resourceGroup = "resource group";
var notificationamespace = "notification name space";
var notificationHubName = "notification hub ";
var serviceCreds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(azureTenantId, azureAppId, azureSecretKey).Result;
MonitorClient monitorClient = new MonitorClient(serviceCreds) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
var resourceUri = $"subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.NotificationHubs/Namespaces/{notificationamespace}/NotificationHubs/{notificationHubName}";
var metricNames = "name.value eq 'notificationhub.pushes'"; //if you want to get the registered devices please change to  registration.all
string timeGrain = " and timeGrain eq duration'PT24H'"; 
string startDate = " and startTime eq 2018-01-01T00:00:00.919Z"; 
string endDate = " and endTime eq 2018-01-04T19:00:00.919Z"; 
var odataFilterMetrics = new ODataQuery<MetricInner>(
            $"{metricNames}{timeGrain}{startDate}{endDate}");
var metrics = monitorClient.Metrics.ListWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceUri, odataFilterMetrics).Result;
```

Test result:

[image]